# Systemd help loading things after a mount

Tags: systemd

wondering if someone can help.

Setting up a seedbox and getting the last few things ironed out

have a sata hat raid that i've got to mount using systemd however when I reboot minidlna and qbittorrent load before the sata hat mounts the raid which causes issues (qbittorrent then can't find the file paths etc)

Wondering if anyone can help with systemd to get minidlna & qbittorrent to load only after the raid has mounted

currently:

"# This file is part of systemd.

systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
(at your option) any later version.
[Unit]
DefaultDependencies=no
Conflicts=umount.target
After=rockpi-sata.service
Before=local-fs.target umount.target

[Mount]
What=/dev/md0
Where=UUID=“3c3a3c08-2aff-4bd6-a68c-5ad8eddb2123”
Type=ext4
Options=defaults,noatime

Make ‘systemctl enable mnt-raidx.mount’ work:
[Install]
WantedBy=local-fs.target"

mounts to /mnt/raidx""

If anyone is able to help it would be greatly appreciated I've spent nearly 100+ hours and countless weekends trying to get numerous things to work and if anyone can save me some time that would be fantastic

Basically want qbittorrent to only load once /mnt/raidx has been mounted and same for minidlna

so if I get a power outage or reboot things just automatically for me

I'm having to use system md due to the sata hat not loading straight away

Comment: Hi, your question is rather hard to read. Did you change config files or created new ones? Which part of your question corresponds to configuration files, shell commands, error messages? How do you expect your system to work, and what is the behavior you get instead?

Answer (score 2):

For my understanding to mount a local attached device, the local filesystem (`local-fs.target`) must be available, so the mount should be done `After=local-fs.target`. Try to replace the line:

```
Before=local-fs.target umount.target
```

with

```
After=local-fs.target
```

in the Unit file.